# How to get floating number between lines and replace it with calculated value in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file which I want to extract floating number in lines and do calculation to make it a different value then replace original number.

e.g. Original file:

```
    *ABC
    1.111e-05
    2.222e-06
    *DEF
    ...
    ...
    *ABC
    3.333e-05
    4.444e-06
    *DEF
    ...
    ...
```

Replaced file (with all decimal number multiplied by 2 and save as new one):

```
    *ABC
    2.222e-05
    4.444e-06
    *DEF
    ...
    ...
    *ABC
    6.666e-05
    8.888e-06
    *DEF
    ...
    ...
```

How do I do this in Perl?
I tried to use

```
$_ =~ /(\*ABC)*(\*DEF)/;
```

to get lines between *ABC and *DEF but it failed...

Comment: So I got an answer for you. Is this the final form of the question ? And are those ABC -- DEF's anything that should be considered ?

Comment: No, *ABC and *DEF not to be considered, and actually there are other texts and numbers before those floating numbers.
e.g.
1 *8435:3 1.11e-05

2 *8435:5 2.22e-05

...

...

Comment: What about integers ?

Comment: @sln The whole floating number needs to be scaled, for example: 1.11e-05 to be replaced by 2.22e-05. Other texts or numbers in the line is not handled, keep original.

Answer (score 3):

Use the flip-flop operator.

```
perl -lpe '$_ *= 2 if /\*ABC/ .. /\*DEF/ and ! /\*/' filename
```

- `-p` reads the input *line by line*, prints each line after processing
- `-l` removes newlines from input, adds them to output
- `! /\*/` excludes the `*ABC` and `*DEF` lines

Comment: Nice... That's why we love Perl

Comment: Sorry I missed something before those floating numbers.

Comment: @Beherit: Rather than invalidating the answer to the original question, you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @choroba, I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can do a callback in a replace format using the form `s///e`
where *e* is the eval operator.

So, you just put the sub name in the replacement side passing the number capture group.

As far as the printf format I leave that up to you.

Perl sample

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $data = <DATA>;


sub Conv
{
    my ($num) = @_;
    return sprintf( "%g", 2 * $num );
}

$data =~ s/(?<![\d.])([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)/Conv($1)/eg;


print $data;

__DATA__

*ABC

315 *15:313 1.111e-05

3232 *41:135 2.222e-06

*DEF

...

...

*ABC

52 *3:1313 3.333e-05

42 *13:753 4.444e-06

*DEF

...

...
```

Output

```
*ABC

315 *15:313 2.222e-005

3232 *41:135 4.444e-006

*DEF

...

...

*ABC

52 *3:1313 6.666e-005

42 *13:753 8.888e-006

*DEF

...

...
```

Here is blow-up of the regex incase you need to modify it.

```
 (?<! [\d.] )
 (                             # (1 start)
      [+-]? 
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
      (?: [eE] [+-]? \d+ )?
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: Doing this between specific lines is the same procedure as this answer, except the regex requires a `\G` construct. Let me know if you need this.